# Implementing quicksort in OCaml: don't understand what's going wrong?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml, quicksort

I am trying to implement the quicksort algorithm in OCaml, and I thought I had it, but it won't compile, and I just can't see what is wrong with it. Here's my code:

```
let rec quicksort list =
    match list with
    [] -> []
    |h::t -> append((quicksort (filter (largerthan h)
    t))(quicksort(filter (smallerthan h) t)));;

let largerthan x y =
    x<y;;

let smallerthan x y =
    x>y;;

let rec append x y =
match x with
[] -> y
| h::t -> h:: append t y;;  

let rec filter f list =
   match list with
   [] -> []
   |h::t -> (if f h = true then h:: filter f t else filter f t);;
```

Now, when I try to use this in OCaml, it says "Error: This expression has type 'a -> 'b
       but an expression was expected of type 'a" while pointing to the last line of my quicksort function.

Does anybody know what's going wrong??

Thanks a lot!

Linus

Edit: Okay, I've gotten rid of the original error (thanks to ADEpt :)). However, now the function just outputs an empty list regardless of the input... Does anybody know what's going on there??

Comment: you do not need for largerthan, just use ( < ) (with the paren). The same is true for smallerthan (using ( > )).

Comment: Note also that this will not realy be a quick quicksort, because append is slow (the first part of the list will be build twice...)

Comment: Note also that `append` and `filter` are already available in the base library, as `(@)` (infix operator, `xs @ yx`) and `List.filter` respectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have extra parens in the "apply" call. Instead of:

> append((quicksort (filter (largerthan h)
>      t))(quicksort(filter (smallerthan h) t))

Write this:

> append (quicksort (filter (largerthan h)  t))
>            (quicksort (filter (smallerthan h) t))

Comment: or even better this:
`let left = quicksort (filter (largerthan h) t) in
 let right = quicksort (filter (smallerthan h) t) in
 append left right` (with proper line endings that I'm not sure I can put in a comment; this looks much more readable)

Comment: Thanks! That took care of the error. However, I just get an empty list as output now... Anybody knows what goes wrong there? :)

Comment: You need to turn 'largetthan' and 'smallerthan' into 'largerthan' and 'smallerorequalthen' :) Otherwise there is no sublist that contain 'h'

Answer (score 1):

For your "second" question: you forgot to add h to the sorted list....

Answer (score 0):

OCaml compiles your program in the order you pass it. It is very strict about this. if you use something, you need to give it, before you use it. If you replace a definition, afterwards the new definition will be used, but before this the old one.

Taking your code from the top down, this is what happens:

```
let rec quicksort list =
    match list with
    [] -> []
    |h::t -> append((quicksort (filter (largerthan h)
    t))(quicksort(filter (smallerthan h) t)));;
```

There is no definition of `largerthan`, `smallerthan`, `filter` or `append` at this time, so the compiler does not know what to do with this.

Reorder your code and several problems will go away.

Comment: Also note: Try to use methods from the standard library or some good replacement of the standard library (e.g. batteries) where possible. `filter` and `append` are already present there.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the explanation. However, I've just put the functions in this order here, in my source files the order is correct :).

Comment: Ok. Always give the code that exhibiting the problem, to avoid confusing others when the code you are giving has additional problems.